# Django social auth login to google redirects to sign up page

Tags: django, pythonanywhere, django-socialauth

Created a link to go to the Google sign in

```
<a class="nav-link pl-3" data-target="#navigationbar" href="https://<my-site>/accounts/google/login/?process=login">Login</a>
```

It redirects to /accounts/social/signup/ instead of showing up the Google sign in page.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4mx1.png)

The very same code works perfectly fine on my local machine and directly goes to google sign in page

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLqfa.png)